# Overlaying Two Idential Graphs

Tags: graphics

I would like to plot a 1D graph with two curves that identically overlap. For example, trivially consider

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

What are the best options to use to plot two overlapping $\sin$ cuves (in the same domain) such that the graphs are (to some extent) visually distinguishable so that the reader can say: *"yes, these two plots are the same"* -- for more interesting cases, though.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not plot the difference of the two functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any curves that might overlap even just a little:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.03], LightGray}, Red},
 PlotLegends -> {"Curve 1", "Curve 2"}]
```

[image: Two identical curves]

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `Show` with `MeshStyle` and/or `PlotStyle`

```
Show[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> 20, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red], MaxRecursion -> 0],
 Plot[Cos[x - Pi/2], {x, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> 20, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.01], Blue], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.0025], Blue], MaxRecursion -> 0]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: 兄弟reputation涨得好猛 :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `Epilog` directly.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}, 
     Epilog -> {Dashed, Red, Line[Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 3, 0.1}]]}]
```

[image]